# Are these three dots part of a filesystem path?

Tags: apt

When running `apt-get install`, I noticed this:

```
Preparing to unpack .../PACKAGENAME_VERSION.deb ...
Unpacking PACKAGENAME (VERSION) ...
```

Note the 3 dots before `/PACKAGENAME_VERSION`.

Do those dots mean anything? Are they part of a filesystem path, like `./` and `../`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's just an [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis). The actual path, in case you're wondering, is more like `/var/cache/apt/archives/foo.deb`. Apparently `dpkg` adds it whenever you supply a path to a package:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i vim-gnome_2%3a7.4.1529-1\~ppa1\~t_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 757002 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack vim-gnome_2%3a7.4.1529-1~ppa1~t_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vim-gnome (2:7.4.1529-1~ppa1~t) over (2:7.4.1529-1~ppa1~t) ...
Setting up vim-gnome (2:7.4.1529-1~ppa1~t) ...

$ sudo dpkg -i ./vim-gnome_2%3a7.4.1529-1\~ppa1\~t_amd64.deb  
(Reading database ... 757002 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../vim-gnome_2%3a7.4.1529-1~ppa1~t_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vim-gnome (2:7.4.1529-1~ppa1~t) over (2:7.4.1529-1~ppa1~t) ...
Setting up vim-gnome (2:7.4.1529-1~ppa1~t) ...
```